# Detect if a object is big enough open cv

Tags: python, opencv, detection

I need some help here plz :)
I have this piece of code with open cv:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    low_red = np.array([100, 100, 100])
    high_red = np.array([225, 225, 225])
    mask = cv2.inRange(frame, low_red, high_red)

    hasColor = np.sum(mask)
    if hasColor > 1000000:
        print(f'Hand opened, infos : {hasColor}')
    elif hasColor > 500000 and hasColor < 1000000:
        print(f'Hand closed, infos : {hasColor}')


    cv2.imshow("Camera", frame)
    cv2.imshow("Mask", mask)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('e'):
        break
```

And I would like that it detect only the objects of a certain size (like a hand) and not the smaller ones.
Thanks for help :)

EDIT: Made some good progress but still don't know how to get the size

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    low = np.array([100, 100, 100])
    high = np.array([225, 225, 225])
    mask = cv2.inRange(frame, low, high)

    cv2.imshow("Camera", frame)

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    ret, tresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, 0)
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(tresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    for i in range(len(contours)):
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(contours[i])
        cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)

    cv2.imshow("Mask", mask)
    cv2.imshow("Hull", frame)


    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('e'):
        break
```

So I think I have to get the value of the bounding box but idk how

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: What does not work and where?  You could get contours and test the area or perimeter of the contours.

Comment: So I edited the post and I'm searching to get the value of the size of the rectangle

Comment: What are those 4 values returned by `cv2.boundingRect()`? Those look promising.

Comment: OH THX So ye i just had to check if w and h were bigger than 150 for example

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved thanks to a kind human,
I just had to add the following code in the for loop:

```
if h > 150 and w > 150:
    cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
```

I just had to check for the size, thanks for your help !